# How do I change my gdb path in Unix?

Tags: unix, command-line, path, gdb, alias

My professor posted this online for a lab this week, but I missed the tutorial and didn't find how to do this. Does anyone know? It is just a simple command line thing, but I have been hunting around and can't seem to figure it out...

Hi everyone,

A new version of gdb (version 6.8) has been installed on the servers csb and csg (but not csh). This new version seems to avoid the problems people have been experiencing with the old version, such as labels not being recognized by the debugger.

The new version of gdb is installed in /usr/local/bin/gdb, while the old version (version 6.2.1) still remains in /opt/sfw/bin/gdb. You may want to create an alias or set your path to point to the new version in your Unix command shell. You can always check the version number of gdb by entering the following at the command line: gdb -version

I am ssh-ing on to the server, and have checked that my version is, in fact, the older one.

I know this is technically a 'superuser' question, but it does have to do with programming (debugger configuration...), and I have asked on superuser and no one responded. Hopefully, fellow programmers will have an answer :)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

badPanda

Comment: You're going to have to tell us your shell (If you don't know, type `echo $SHELL` and paste in the result) so we can tell you what startup file you'll need to modify to set your PATH/alias

Comment: Thanks! The result was: /bin/tcsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an alias:

```
alias gdb /usr/local/bin/gdb
```

You don't change the "GDB search path", you change the executable search path.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH
```

You can both of  these to your .bash_profile or .bashrc

I would probably go with the alias.

Edit: this is all assuming bash. It should work in tcsh too

Comment: Look at .tcshrc file in your home directory to perform these commands at every startup for tcsh